# How to make AuthorizationChecker.isGranted disable cache in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've got a huge problem with it's session algorithms. As for my project's design, I should manage users' roles through their groups. And everything is stored in the database. How can I force symfony to update user session's roles every time?

Answer (score 1):

I just have solved this trouble by adding

```
security:
    always_authenticate_before_granting: true
```